# UIDocumentPickerViewController when initialized in a framework shows files as grayed out

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I want to initialize an UIDocumentPickerViewController from a framework. But, the files (.pdf) are shown as grayed out in the document picker when using below code in framework. The code works fine when UIDocumentPickerViewController is initialized in the main app target. This is what I use.

```
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.pdf])
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are having `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in the framework, so better way to do this is to use `custom UIViewController` and implement all the delegates of `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in that view controller. Then in your main app, you can inherit that custom UIViewController and call parent APIs to load `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was, I was trying to present `UIDocumentPickerViewController` from `window.rootViewController` as I don't have access to a `UIViewController` from my main target. I created a `UIViewController` in my framework and presented `UIDocumentPickerViewController` from there and it worked. But, still I am not sure what is the difference in presenting `UIDocumentPickerViewController` from a `window.rootViewController` vs from a real `UIViewController` object. Well, both are UIViewControllers